# Operation on df with pipe and groupe_by()

Tags: r, dplyr

Here below my df

[image: df1]

I can't figure out how to make basic operation on numerical column only within each region and sector
I'd like to have  (max (Colonne 3  in region and Sector of X ) - X for instance

I started my code with

```
df2<-
df1 %>%  
groupe_by(Region,Sector) %>%
```

but then i don't how to make operation on all the other column

Comment: Hello Pierre, please consider including the output from the following function: `dput(df1)`. Also, please include an example of the data you wish to have at the end of your procedure.

Comment: `group_by` shouldn't have an `e`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ? (BTW:Please make sure what is your desired output. We are here help you out with your specific questions, not guess what you want.)

For this "Colonne 3", I assuming it is column 4.

```
df2=df1 %>% group_by(Region,Sector) %>%slice(which.max(BEST_EPS_YOY_GTH))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi sorry i didn't find how to share my df...
Here below, just the first column of my df
what i would like to compute and saved in an new df is for instance with the first line  :

max(BEST_EPS_YOY_GTH if Region = Japan && Sector = Health care) - (-0.12543111)

Second line : 
max(BEST_EPS_YOY_GTH if Region = The Americas && Sector = Consumer discretionary) - (0.02846056)

and doing this for all the lines all the others column i have in my df (i have 12 of them like BEST_EPS_YOY_GTH

Not sure if it's clear but many thanks for your help.

```html
<html><style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
 {font-family:"MS Mincho";
 panose-1:2 2 6 9 4 2 5 8 3 4;}
@font-face
 {font-family:"MS Mincho";
 panose-1:2 2 6 9 4 2 5 8 3 4;}
@font-face
 {font-family:Calibri;
 panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
 {font-family:Tahoma;
 panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
@font-face
 {font-family:"\@MS Mincho";
 panose-1:2 2 6 9 4 2 5 8 3 4;}
@font-face
 {font-family:"Lucida Console";
 panose-1:2 11 6 9 4 5 4 2 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
 {margin:0cm;
 margin-bottom:.0001pt;
 font-size:11.0pt;
 font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
 {mso-style-priority:99;
 color:blue;
 text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
 {mso-style-priority:99;
 color:purple;
 text-decoration:underline;}
pre
 {mso-style-priority:99;
 mso-style-link:"Pr\00E9format\00E9 HTML Car";
 margin:0cm;
 margin-bottom:.0001pt;
 font-size:10.0pt;
 font-family:"Courier New";}
p.MsoAcetate, li.MsoAcetate, div.MsoAcetate
 {mso-style-priority:99;
 mso-style-link:"Texte de bulles Car";
 margin:0cm;
 margin-bottom:.0001pt;
 font-size:8.0pt;
 font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif";}
span.EmailStyle17
 {mso-style-type:personal-compose;
 font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
 color:windowtext;}
span.TextedebullesCar
 {mso-style-name:"Texte de bulles Car";
 mso-style-priority:99;
 mso-style-link:"Texte de bulles";
 font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif";}
span.PrformatHTMLCar
 {mso-style-name:"Pr\00E9format\00E9 HTML Car";
 mso-style-priority:99;
 mso-style-link:"Pr\00E9format\00E9 HTML";
 font-family:"Courier New";}
.MsoChpDefault
 {mso-style-type:export-only;}
@page WordSection1
 {size:612.0pt 792.0pt;
 margin:70.85pt 70.85pt 70.85pt 70.85pt;}
div.WordSection1
 {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--></head><body lang=FR link=blue vlink=purple><div class=WordSection1><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:10.25pt;background:#0B0A09;word-break:break-all'><span lang=EN-US style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Lucida Console";color:#FCFFE0'>Ticker&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sector&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Region&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;BEST_EPS_YOY_GTH<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:10.25pt;background:#0B0A09;word-break:break-all'><span lang=EN-US style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Lucida Console";color:#FCFFE0'>A US Equity&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; A US Equity&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Health Care&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Japan&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; -0.12543111<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:10.25pt;background:#0B0A09;word-break:break-all'><span lang=EN-US style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Lucida Console";color:#FCFFE0'>AAP US Equity&nbsp;&nbsp; AAP US Equity Consumer Discretionary The Americas&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 0.02846056<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:10.25pt;background:#0B0A09;word-break:break-all'><span lang=EN-US style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Lucida Console";color:#FCFFE0'>ABBV US Equity ABBV US Equity&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Health Care The Americas&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; -0.03884949<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:10.25pt;background:#0B0A09;word-break:break-all'><span lang=EN-US style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Lucida Console";color:#FCFFE0'>ABT US Equity&nbsp;&nbsp; ABT US Equity&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Health Care The Americas&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; -0.15789776<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:10.25pt;background:#0B0A09;word-break:break-all'><span lang=EN-US style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Lucida Console";color:#FCFFE0'>ACN US Equity&nbsp;&nbsp; ACN US Equity Information Technology The Americas&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; -0.19914068<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:10.25pt;background:#0B0A09;word-break:break-all'><span lang=EN-US style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Lucida Console";color:#FCFFE0'>ADBE US Equity ADBE US Equity Information Technology The Americas&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 0.14954818<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:10.25pt;background:#0B0A09;word-break:break-all'><span lang=EN-US style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Lucida Console";color:#FCFFE0'>AEM CN Equity&nbsp;&nbsp; AEM CN Equity&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Materials&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Japan&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 0.12508785<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:10.25pt;background:#0B0A09;word-break:break-all'><span lang=EN-US style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Lucida Console";color:#FCFFE0'>AES US Equity&nbsp;&nbsp; AES US Equity&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Utilities The Americas&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; -0.06861536<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:10.25pt;background:#0B0A09;word-break:break-all'><span lang=EN-US style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Lucida Console";color:#FCFFE0'>AET US Equity&nbsp;&nbsp; AET US Equity&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Health Care The Americas&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; -0.17615952<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:10.25pt;background:#0B0A09;word-break:break-all'><span lang=EN-US style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Lucida Console";color:#FCFFE0'>AFL US Equity&nbsp;&nbsp; AFL US Equity&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Financials Asia Pacific&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; -0.31764175<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span lang=EN-US><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span lang=EN-US><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p></div></body></html>
```